How to Implement GraphQLQueryPager in Apollo iOS for Pagination?
I'm currently working on implementing pagination in my iOS application using Apollo for GraphQL queries. I came across the Apollo iOS documentation on pagination, which mentions a GraphQLQueryPager for handling pagination. However, I am unable to find any reference or implementation details about GraphQLQueryPager in the Apollo iOS SDK.
Could someone provide guidance or examples on how to properly implement GraphQLQueryPager for pagination in Apollo iOS? Specifically, I'm looking for:
An example of how to set up and use GraphQLQueryPager for paginating through a list of items.
Any required configurations or setup steps that I might be missing.
Alternative approaches to handle pagination if GraphQLQueryPager is no longer supported or available.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/pagination/introduction#using-a-graphqlquerypager
Here are some details about my setup:

I am using the latest version of Apollo iOS via Swift Package Manager (SPM).
I have imported the Apollo package successfully in my project.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
